# Notes to learners?

Tags: discussion

Look at this answer (try to ignore the comments if you can:): [Would used for willingness in the present](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/would-used-for-willingness-in-the-present/20086#20086).  I was just dying to add this:

> Consider this learners: How would saying "Bruce would *have loaned* the money" affect the meaning of the sentence?

I suspect that the idea will be shot down if proposed as an addendum to an answer, but what about leaving that kind of thing as a comment?

Comment: I think it belongs in the answer *if* you immediately proceed to answer it. Inviting the reader to answer it would be a sound technique with native-speaker learners, who know what it means but not how; but NNS leaners are at a loss precisely because they don't know what it means. ... But I may be overcautious because this question involves the semantics of modals, which is a quagmire I try to stay on the outermost fringes of!

Comment: But..but...but..posing it as a question to ponder is soooo much easier! :)